# PHP Files Array Has Data But Size and Error Are 0

Tags: php, file-upload

So I have a form on a page that uses enctype="multipart/form-data", and I have a single file field on the form named 'upload_file'.  When I submit the form and use print_r($_FILES), I get:

```
Array
(
    [upload_file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test-Blank-PDF.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpvr5N3Z
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 0
        )
```

You will notice both the error and size are 0. I use the following code to process the upload:

```
$file = "/tmp/" . $_FILES['upload_file']['name'];

if ($_FILES['upload_file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'], $file);
}
```

I get the file ($file) created at /tmp/Test-Blank-PDF.pdf, but it is 0 bytes (empty).  If I also try to save/read the value of $_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'] with file_get_contents before script completion, it is also empty.

This is running on CentOS 6 with PHP 5.6.  Other forms upload and process files fine, although they run via AJAX, but all still use $_FILES in the back-end to save.  This is the only one that doesn't.

I have verified various PHP settings (file_uploads are on and post_max_size and such are all set properly). My form is using POST, and the $_FILES array does print data (e.g. not empty). I checked Apache's error logs (both SSL and plain) and no errors in either. I even turned off iptables to test, and it still failed.

Any ideas?  I'm at a loss here.  : /

Comment: How large is the file actually? Are you sure it doesn't exceed the ini value of PHP?

Comment: Positive.  The php.ini is set at 8M (MB).  The file is only 30k.  When I upload it in other parts of the site it uploads fine.

Comment: I went ahead and moved the code to use AJAX like the rest of the site, as I never could determine what the problem was. : (